# Make sections come below each other

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create multiple sections which are of size of viewport and i need to align test in center and middle of the sections. I tried giving `display: table-cell`, to vertical align the text but then the sections come next to each other.

I have created the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kp0jbuko/)

html:

```
   <div id="main">
        <section id="home">
            gf
        </section>
        <section id="about">
            gh
        </section>
        <section id="contactMe">
            gf
        </section>
  </div>
```

css:

```
#main{
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#home{
    background-color: green;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#about{
    background-color: blue;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100vh;
    width: 10vw;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#contactMe{
    background-color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

If anymore information is required mention in comment. Thanks.

edit: Sections should come below eachother

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one quick way of making it work.  Wrap your text in a `div`, and then apply `display: table` to the `section` elements and then `display: table-cell` to the `div`'s.

```css
#main{
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#main section {
    background-size: cover;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: table;
}
#main section div {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
#home{
    background-color: green;
}
#about{
    background-color: blue;
}
#contactMe{
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <section id="home">
    <div>gf</div>
  </section>
  <section id="about">
    <div>gh</div>
  </section>
  <section id="contactMe">
    <div>gf</div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankx a lot. Works perfect. Just to know, this must be the recommended way to achieve this ryt.

Comment: This approach is well supported by modern browsers.  There may be other ways of doing this using absolute positioning and inline-blocks, but I suspect that you would still need a nested element approach.  You need an outer element to detect the viewport dimensions and within it, a child element to take care of the vertical alignment.